# Define a create function in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to create an "administration" page where users can create a "match", giving it a name, and display a list of the matches I created to an other page. I also would like to have a "delete" button to delete a match.

I have this model:

```
class Match(models.Model):
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Teams)
    identite = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    teamA = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    teamB = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    sport = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_start = models.DateTimeField()
    date_end = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.identite
```

I created this function inside the model:

```
def create_match(self,name):
    return self.create('name')
```

Then, I try to create a form in the html of my administration page:

```
 <form method="post" action=".">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <p><label for="Team A">Team A:</label> <input id="Team A" type="text" class="required"   name="Team A" maxlength="30"></p>
 <p><label for="Team B">Team B:</label> <input id="Team B" type="text" class="required" name="Team B" maxlength="30"></p>
  (...)
 <input type="submit" value="" />
 </form>
```

So my questions are:

How can I call my function "create_match" so that when I click the submit button it creates a match in my DB with the data I filled in?
How can I add this match to a list so that I can display this list to an other page?
Finally, how can I delete the match from this list without deleting it from the DB?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Where is your view? What is the `return self.create('name')`? Are you aware that the default model manager has a `create` method?

Comment: For now I didn't do anything in my view. I just created it and it returns the html I pasted in my question. And I didn't know that there is a create method. I'll check that. The thing is that I don't how to do to call this function when someone clicks the submit button - I know it's a very basic question, but I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Consider using a [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) in conjunction with a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django provides built in functionality to generate forms based on models these are called [Model Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Additionally generally to "create" new models just instantiate your model class and assign the correct values and save it.

Also django provides a built in administration page that allows you to register a model and allows a user to create/delete/modify records in your db.  It is trivial to add a model to the django admin and get this functionality.

Comment: Thank you, I found the function Model.objects.create(). But how can I call this function in the html so that when someone clicks the submit button it creates the match?

Comment: you don't relaly do it in the html.  You can send a request to a view with the correct data.  Creation should take place inside of a view not a template